# mongodb : use variable instead of property name in find

Tags: mongodb

I need to add condition to find depends to variable value : if it is null don't add to condition if not null - add.
I am new in mongodb and for example I gen get it from SQL

```
DECLARE Variable int = null
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE field = isnull(Variable ,field)
```

In mongodb I try to do find

```
let Variable = "aa";
db.Table.find({
  
         $or: [{field:Variable },{Variable : null }]
         
})
```

But its don't work as expected
Please assist

Answer (score 1):

Use `{ [Variable] : null }`

```
db.Table.find({
   $or: [{field:Variable },{ [Variable] : null }]       
})
```

---

```js
let Variable = "aa";

const obj = { [Variable] : null };

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Could you please write whole script ?

Comment: @Michael https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/

Comment: I need second condition in OR true when value of Variable is null

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/